# Proving that $2$-D parabolic coordinates are orthogonal

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems

How can we prove that the parabolic coordinate system in two dimensions is orthogonal? I tried using the dot product, but don't know where to start or what basis vectors can be used in two dimensions. In three dimensions I would normally show that the dot product of the basis vectors is zero, but don't know the $2$-D basis vectors for parabolic coordinates, any hints?

The $2$-D system is defined as:

$$ x= \mu \kappa$$
$$ y = \frac{1}{2}(\mu^2-\kappa^2) $$

Comment: I corrected a sign error in the formula for $y$.

Comment: Add $z=z$ and you have a 3D system that you know how to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of your coordinates as a parameterization ${\bf r}$ of the appropriate subset of the $xy$-plane in the coordinate. Then, in the coordinate basis $(x, y)$,
\begin{align}
\partial_{\kappa} &= {\bf r}_{\kappa} = (\mu, -\kappa) \\
\partial_{\mu}    &= {\bf r}_{\mu}    = (\kappa, \mu) .
\end{align}

> Computing gives $$\partial_{\kappa} \cdot \partial_{\mu} = 0.$$